# Button only appears when you start inputting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is what Javascript function for to make the button only appears when the user start inputting to the textbox, if its not the button will not appear.

Here's my code

```
<label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4">
    <p class="left">Color/s</p>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <input name="color" class="form-control req" autocomplete = "off" />
    <input type="button" value="Add Color" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you got to do is add an `input` listener and check if the input is empty or not.

```js
var button = $('input[type=button]');
button.hide();
//hide it at the beginning.
$('input[name=color]').on('input', function() {
  //If input changes
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    //If it's not empty show it
    button.show();
  } else {
    //If it's empty hide it
    button.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4">
  <p class="left">Color/s</p>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
  <input name="color" class="form-control req" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="button" value="Add Color" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the `input` event,

```
$('input[name="color"]').on('input',function(){
  $('input[type="button"]')[0].disabled = (this.value.trim().length == 0);
}).trigger('input');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t0v1r49L/)

Comment: Does this affect my other button in the same page as well?

Comment: @Vista Yes it does. Give some other unique identity to that button, or just use `$(this).next('button')`

Answer (score 4):

Hide your button (via style)

```
<label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Color/s</p></label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input name="color" class="form-control req" autocomplete = "off" />
    <input type="button" value="Add Color" style="display:none" />
```

add JS like this

```
$( ".form-control" ).keypress(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).unbind('keypress');
});
```

Comment: Good solution, but I would also unbind the control on the first key-press. Otherwise the event keeps firing unnecessarily.

Comment: And when they delete all the text? unbind kills it. Edge case: Also paste without the keyboard would not be caught.

Comment: I think it's actually better to keep button as user already knows about it :).
Anyway, you point is valid and it is up to design. It's easy to change anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Using just CSS, you can show and hide the button with the required attribute.

```css
input[name="color"]:valid + input[type="button"] {
   display: inline;  
}

input[name="color"]:invalid + input[type="button"] {
   display: none;  
}
```

```html
<label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4">
  <p class="left">Color/s</p>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
  <input name="color" class="form-control req" autocomplete="off" required/>
  <input type="button" value="Add Color" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeyup` function to activate the button